# Laravel Missing argument 1 in get()

Tags: php, database, laravel, model

I am trying to get all records from a table named 'producers', but I get the following error.

```
Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), called in /var/www/html/wines/storage/framework/views/ac350063efb624ac50d199628897fd7d72bc196c.php on line 63 and defined (View: /var/www/html/wines/resources/views/admin/producers.blade.php)
```

Here are my files:
(migration)

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProducerTable extends Migration    {
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('producers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('producer_name');
            $table->string('phone_number');
            $table->string('user_id')->unique();
            $table->string('avatar')->default('default.jpg');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('producers');
    }
}
```

My ProducerController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
class ProducerController extends Controller    {
    public function __construct()        {
        $this->middleware('isProducer');
    }    }
```

The producer model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Producer extends Model    {
    protected $table = 'producers';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','producer_name', 'phone_number','user_id','avatar'
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
    ];
}
```

Then when I use

```
public function admin_producers()    {
        return view('admin.producers',array('user'=>Auth::user(),'producer'=>Producer::get()));
    }
```

on the controller to get all my records I get that error. I have also tried with Producer::all() but with the same result, no luck.
I am doing something stupid here?

Comment: Can you show us the method `Producer::get`? I think this method requires an `ID`. Can you show us also the method `Producer::all`, if you desire to retrieve all Producers?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My problem was not that get but the one in the blade: @foreach($producer->get() as $producer_r). Changed to @foreach($producer->all() as $producer_r) and is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: How can I mark this as solved?

Comment: OK. I suggest you to put the result of `$producer->all()` in a variable, because at each loop on the foreach, you re-execute the call.

Comment: If you want to mark solved, reply to your first post and mark it as the answer.

Comment: How can I do that? And thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115046/discussion-between-keupsonite-and-scottbear).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Eloquent `all()` method will return all of the results in the model's table. Use `get()` only, when you need to add constraints to queries.

So, use `all()` instead of `get()`.